# Leaving member functions undefined

Tags: c++

Is it legal in C++ to leave certain member functions of a class undefined, and still use the class, except for these functions? For example:

```
// A.hpp
struct A {
    void f();
    void g();
};

// A.cpp
#include "A.h"
void A::f() { }

// A_g.cpp
#include "A.h"
void A::g() { }

// main.cpp
#include "A.h"
int main() {
    A* a = new A;
    a->f();
}
```

`A::g()` would be defined in a separate `A_g.cpp` file that gets compiled&linked only for certain build settings.

In the real code these are large parts of code with additional dependencies to external libraries that are only needed for certain build products.

Are there limits in how `A` can be used, if not all of its member functions are defined?

Comment: Private unimplemented constructors were the old way to `= delete;` them, so it's probably not UB

Comment: After the edit all functions are implemented, just in different compilation units.

Comment: @churill  The question is asking "if you compile and link just A.cpp and main.cpp, is the result legal C++".  I think the listing should *not* include A_g.cpp (and possibly merge it all into one file with definition of `A`, of `A::f`, and of `main` all in the single file).

Comment: You aren't showing a class its a structure.  Try using the keyword virtual which means the method can be implemented, if you add = 0 after the prototype its a pure virtual function which must be declared if not the structure/class remains abstract until a derived instance provides a full declaration of all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A function is only required to be defined if it is odr-used.

> One and only one definition of every non-inline function or variable that is odr-used (see below) is required to appear in the entire program (including any standard and user-defined libraries). The compiler is not required to diagnose this violation, but the behavior of the program that violates it is undefined.
>
> 4) Functions are ODR-used if
>
> - A function whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression (including named function, overloaded operator, user-defined conversion, user-defined placement forms of operator new, non-default initialization) is odr-used if it is selected by overload resolution, except when it is an unqualified pure virtual member function or a pointer-to-member to a pure virtual function (since C++17).
> - virtual member function is odr-used if it is not a pure virtual member function (addresses of virtual member functions are required to construct the vtable)
> - An allocation or deallocation function for a class is odr-used by a new expression appearing in a potentially-evaluated expression
> - A deallocation function for a class is odr-used by a delete expression appearing in a potentially-evaluated expression
> - A non-placement allocation or deallocation function for a class is odr-used by the definition of a constructor of that class.
> - A non-placement deallocation function for a class is odr-used by the definition of the destructor of that class, or by being selected by the lookup at the point of definition of a virtual destructor
> - An assignment operator in a class T that is a member or base of another class U is odr-used by an implicitly-defined copy-assignment or move-assignment functions of U.
> - A constructor (including default constructors) for a class is odr-used by the initialization that selects it.
> - A destructor for a class is odr-used if it is potentially invoked

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition

Answer (score 3):

To restate your question:  Is the following complete program legal?

```
struct A {
    void f() {};
    void g();  // Declared but not defined (and not used).
};

int main() {
    A a;
    a.f();
}
```

## Yes

I am using [n4296](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) which is the C++14 draft, but this has not changed over the years.

9.3 p4 [class.mfct] says:

> There shall be at most one definition of a non-inline member function in a program; no diagnostic is required.

Note the "at most" - thus zero definitions are allowed.